# Prevent browser from caching uploading images

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, image-processing, no-cache

After loading page, I want to upload different images to server several times.
Each time I choose image, ajax uploads it to server and then shows on screen.
Problem is that it continues to upload the rest images after I choose them one after another, but shows on the screen only image N1 each time.

Script:

```
..............    

On File input box change
    var file = this.files[0];
then run ajax
$.ajax({
                    url: "/users/img_upload", 
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: new FormData(formdata[0]),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
```

imageIsLoaded function is here

```
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
$('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
```

Now after I upload first image, it continues to show only first image even after I upload second, third and etc. I thought `cache: false,`  will prevent this but, unfortunately first image is cached :( Any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: `POST` requests aren't cached. Also what is `file`?

Comment: check question again, I've added missing string

Comment: Edited question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on a global file object. This is not really dependable because you do not know what happens to the variable.

its better to envelop the whole into a function that you call whilst passing the parameters needed.

Also you are passing a new FormData(formData[0]) which also gave erros in my tests.

This is what I came up with that works

```js
function runme(files) {
    formData = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });
    formData.append('userpic', file, 'upload.jpg');
               $.ajax({
                    url: "/users/img_upload", 
                    type: "POST", 
                   data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                    },
                    error:function(data){
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                    }
            });
}

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
$('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" onchange="runme(this.files);">
    <img src="#" id="img">
```

Comment: Modified answer. I have a working demo that changes the image.

Comment: That does not work then in PHP
That's why I had to send 
data: new FormData(formdata[0])

Comment: if you do in php `var_dump($_POST['userpic']);` what do you get?

Comment: On PHP side I'm waiting for $_FILES["file"]["type"]. Shall I wait for $_POST['userpic'] ?

Comment: Well, yea, because that's what you are passing along to the form if you use my method. `formData.append('userpic',` the userpick in this case defines the post field variable in php

Comment: Well OK, suppose I send userpic. which equals to $_FILES["file"]["type"]] probably.

But what then should I do with other parameters which I wait for on Server Side
such as :
$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
           $_FILES["file"]["type"];
            $_FILES["file"]["error"];
            $_FILES["file"]["size"];

Comment: Just do a `var_dump($_POST);` and `console.log(data)` it in your success function. Or see what renaming userpic to file does for you.

Comment: success function receives "array(0) {
}"

How can I access the file and it's parameters ?

Comment: FormData support starts from following desktop browsers versions. IE 10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+

For more detail, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData

which browser are you on?

Comment: Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m |  
Google Chrome is up to date.

Comment: By the way the whole process is working if I use data: new FormData(formdata[0])

Just have problems in JS with image caching, but PHP side works perfectly.

Comment: i've updated the snippet. and if it works with formdata[0] go with that, but if you use that does the image still update or not?

Comment: I think this code is not working. even in your example.